# xargs with args from echo and -I {} doesn't appear to work...?

Tags: xargs

I try to use xargs with both `-n 1` and `-I {}` at the same time, but with no success...

Let's say you want to move `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt` to other names:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
    mv ${i}.txt ${i}_ren.txt
done
```

now I try to pass the `1 2 3` values to `xargs` via `echo`, but it does not appear to work.
I use:

```
echo 1 2 3 | xargs -n 1 -I {} mv {}.txt {}_ren.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found a way out by using: inline `echo 2 3 4 | xargs -n 1 | xargs -I {} mv {}.txt {}_ren.txt`, but I would prefer to use something less intricated

Comment: it is probably impossible to combine -n and -I , see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=31858&gt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are doing wrong because `-I` is for **each input line**.

You can either replace space with new line by:

```sh
echo 1 2 3 | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I {} -P0 mv {}.txt {}_ren.txt
```

or use `seq` instead of `echo` by:

```sh
seq 3 | xargs -I {} -P0 mv {}.txt {}_ren.txt
```

or without `-I` by

```sh
echo 1 2 3 |
  tr ' ' '\n' |
  sed 's/.*/&.txt &_ren.txt/' |
  xargs -n2 -P0 mv
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems  impossible to combine xargs options `-n` and `-I` ,

see e.g. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=31858&gt

However it is possible to use only one pipe instead of

```
echo 2 3 4 | xargs -n 1 | xargs -I {} mv {}.txt {}_ren.txt
```

to achieve the same effect.

For this  the newline at the end of the `echo` output has to be disabled (system-dependent);
using space as delimeter for `xargs`:

```
echo -n 2 3 4 | xargs -d " " -I {} mv {}.txt {}_ren.txt
```

Unfortunately this solution is probably not less intricated.